# localhost shortcuts

Tags: apache

I have php and apache enabled and a folder `test` located in my `~/Sites`. Is there anyway to access it thanks to the address `http://test.dev` instead of `http://localhost/~user/test` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a "[Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)".  Here's how I set them up:

- Edit `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, and change

  ```
  # Virtual hosts
  # Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```

  to be:

  ```
  # Virtual hosts
  Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  ```
- Edit `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and add an entry that's something like this:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Users/dave/Sites"
      ServerName test.dev
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Edit `/private/etc/hosts` and add this entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1 test.dev
  ```
- Restart your webserver (I use `sudo apachectl restart`)

There are some example virtual host definitions in the `httpd-vhost.conf` file that are there to show you what the syntax looks like.  They look like this:

```
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Add `#` signs to the beginning of those lines to comment them out.

---

An alternative to this is to use an app like [VirtualHostX](http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/) to do this for you ($35).

---

**Edit 5 Dec 2011**:

Here's a new blog post by the makers of [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com) on how they set this up:

http://preppeller.com/2011/12/04/setting-up-virtual-hosts-on-your-local-os-x-apache/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... I also tried restarting by unchecking-checking the Web Share in the System Preferences, but it is also not working.

Comment: @aliouftw Run "`apachectl -S`" in terminal to see if you've misconfigured something

Comment: it returns [this](http://pastebin.com/WUdk6CvX)

Comment: @aliouftw updated answer.

Comment: also not working. `apachectl -S` is now returning [this](http://pastebin.com/KP2Ph2Cq)

Comment: @aliouftw please post your `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `hosts` files.

Comment: [httpd-conf](http://pastebin.com/GCaxix66), [hosts](http://pastebin.com/AiU6XcSA)

Comment: @aliouftw sorry, i'm not sure what the problem is. i set my stack up a long time ago.